# ¿Por qué la validación del email aparece en inglés?

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario, idiomas

Si uno va a la sección [Mis inicios de sesión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current) y luego se dirige a *añadir más inicios de sesión* aparece una pantalla donde agregarlo.

En ella, la validación del email está en inglés y no la encontré en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He buscado por si estuviera en la lista de ignoradas y no he conseguido encontrarla. De todas maneras, no soy capaz de reproducirlo: a mí me aparece en español:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Tras una ardua investigación llevada a cabo por @fedorqui y por mí mismo, hemos descubierto que esa cadena no proviene de Stack Exchange, sino del navegador Chrome.

Como se explica en [este post en Google+](https://plus.google.com/+KentTamura/posts/VTLjtVMwXE9), es una validación añadida por Chrome a partir de su versión 31 junto con todas estas:

```
<input type="email" value="foo">
===> Please include an '@' in the email address. 'foo' is missing an '@'.
<input type="email" value="foo@">
===> Please enter a part following '@'.'foo@' is incomplete.
<input type="email" value="@example">
===> Please enter a part followed by '@'.'@example' is incomplete.
<input type="email" value="foo @example">
===> A part followed by '@' should not contain the symbol ' '.
<input type="email" value="foo@example,com">
===> A part following '@' should not contain the symbol ','.
<input type="email" value="foo@example..com">
===> '.' is used at a wrong position in 'example..com'.
```

Comment: Anda, ¿será que pertenece a alguna aplicación externa que coge la configuración del navegador? Yo lo tengo configurado en inglés.

Comment: Pues es posible, porque no aparece en traducir.win ni en transifex...tenemos un misterio entre manos :)

Comment: @fedorqui Ahora que lo estoy pensando...es bastante posible que sea una aviso del navegador. Supongo que al ser un input type=email, el navegador hace alguna pequeña validación y muestra ese mensaje

Comment: @fedorqui resuelto: https://plus.google.com/+KentTamura/posts/VTLjtVMwXE9

Comment: Sí, confirmado: [es algo que tiene Google Chrome desde la versión 31](https://plus.google.com/+KentTamura/posts/VTLjtVMwXE9)

Comment: Me ganaste por 5 segundos!! Jajajaja esto me pasa por poner título al enlace

Comment: @fedorqui vas a eliminar la pregunta? si no,lo añado a la respuesta

Comment: Mmmm si eso dejemos la pregunta de momento. Si luego la gente cree que no vale la pena tenerla, pues ya la borro. Así que sí, añádelo a la respuesta si puedes :)

Comment: buen trabajo @Pikoh :) efectivamente, esa cadena no está en el código fuente de SO